# How to get xhr data in javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm a newbie at javascript and I made this script which runs on page load:

```
function checkItem(itemToCheck) {
  console.log(`Checking if ${itemToCheck} is checked`)
  var url = `https://list.s40.repl.co/api/get-status/${itemToCheck}`;

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", url);

  xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }};

  xhr.send();
  if (status === 200) {
    console.log("The request worked")
    if (response == `True`) {
      console.log(`${itemToCheck} is true`)
      var checkbox = document.getElementById(`${itemToToggle}-checkbox`)
      //Control the checkbox
    }
  }
}
```

It never outputs the "The request worked" text, and it seems to be because the xhr.status and xhr.responseText are blank outside of that function they're in.
I know nothing about javascript and I don't know how to fix this. All I want to do is be able to request data and then do something with it if it equals true. Please help

Comment: Move the `if (status === 200) { ... }` part inside `xhr.onreadystatechange`.

Comment: @WaisKamal Now it doesn't run any of the javascript

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: @WaisKamal no, there aren't any. If you want to see the code for the full website go here: https://replit.com/@s40/List

Answer (score 0):

I get `xhr.status == 0`, which means the request failed. When I run the request through postman, I get an SSL error (certificate has expired). That is probably why the request fails.

Running it with `fetch` is not a problem though. So fetch seems to skip the SSL error. There doesn't seem to be a way to make `XMLHttpRequest` ignore this SSL error, though.

```
fetch(`https://list.s40.repl.co/api/get-status/2`)
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(console.log)
```

I advise you to check if you can just use fetch for the task. Only very old browsers don't support it: https://caniuse.com/fetch

It is higher level and `async` by nature. You should generally prefer `async` code over synchronous when writing for the browser, as synchronous code blocks execution quickly and slows down your browser application or makes it even freeze.

Comment: I tried using fetch, but it seems that I probably made a mistake in the html because no javascript runs at all. I put in a console.log and it didn't even run

Comment: Try `console.log(checkItem, checkItem())` in the `<body>` of `list.html`. What's the output?